# Google Sitemap grid not being filled/shown

Tags: magento

On our Magento 1.6.2 website we have enabled Google Sitemaps and added some manually with updates through cron.

What happens now is that the page Catalog > Google Sitemap in it's filters tells us that 4 records were found.
But it doesn't show anything below the filters.

Through looking at the source code I've found that the div with class sitemapGrid only has a total height of 33px and the div with class grid that should display the sitemaps only has a total height of 7px, 6 of which are padding.

The sitemapGrid_table is 0px high, with a 1px border.

But no tr nor td.

After some more digging I've found that the file in which it all happens is design > adminhtml > default > default > template > widget > grid.phtml

The page runs till the end of the first foreach after "grid" and then stops.

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="hor-scroll">
    <table cellspacing="0" class="data" id="<?php echo $this->getId() ?>_table">
        <?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?>
        <col <?php echo $_column->getHtmlProperty() ?> />
        <?php endforeach; ?> <!-- Runs to here and then stops executing, but who knows why? -->
        <?php if ($this->getHeadersVisibility() || $this->getFilterVisibility()): ?>
            <thead>
                <?php if ($this->getHeadersVisibility()): ?>
                    <tr class="headings">
                    <?php foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?>
                        <th<?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtmlProperty() ?>><span class="nobr"><?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtml() ?></span></th>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->getFilterVisibility()): ?>
                    <tr class="filter">
                    <?php $i=0;foreach ($this->getColumns() as $_column): ?>
                        <th<?php echo $_column->getHeaderHtmlProperty() ?>><?php echo $_column->getFilterHtml() ?></th>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif ?>
            </thead>
```

If I comment out the first foreach, the code keeps running till it ends the first foreach in "headings". And so on (comment out one, runs till end of next one, ...)

Anyone have any idea on where the problem really lies and/or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So,
Long story short:
exception.log wasn't being filled so once that was solved I got to see that Magento couldn't find a certain blocktype.
Solved an error in config.xml and it all works just fine.